# How does BreezeJS track property changes

Tags: javascript, key-value-observing, breeze

I am curious about how BreezeJS is able to determine which properties of an entity have changed and still support IE8?

I am in the need of similar functionality for a library I am building.  JavaScript setters/getters would be the easiest solution however they are not support on non-dom objects in IE8.

Are they using something like : https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583 : or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the "modelLibrary" in use, for backbone and knockout Breeze uses the "observability" of the underlying knockout or backbone objects.  For something like AngularJS, where there is no requirement for an underlying object to support observability, Breeze uses its "backingStore" model library which does something very similar to the Object.watch implementation that you are pointing to in your question.

The "backingStore" implementation, like the Object.watch implementation above will NOT work on IE8 because there is no support for javascripts "defineProperty".

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the backingStore implementation does not work in IE8, then why does BreezeJS say they support it?

Comment: Breeze supports Knockout and Backbone model libraries on IE8, but not the "backingStore" library ( used by Angular).