# How do I bind the column with the property?

Tags: breeze, slickgrid

I'm trying connect `slickgrid` and `breeze.js`, but I got a problem.

breeze generates the `js` model for you, and the object properties has get and set methods like:

```
var p1 = myobj.property1();
var p2 = myobj.property2();

myobj.property1("Test");
```

But in the `slickgrid` columns model, how do I bind the column with the property?

```
columns : [
        {
            id: "id",
            name: "ID",
            field: "property1"  //this way I only see for every row on the page the text "function..."
        },
        {
            id: "prop2", name: "prop2", field: "property2"
        }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the breeze "backingStore" adapter instead of the default "ko" (knockout) adapter.

This requires just a single line of Breeze configuration near the top of the file

```
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
```

The backingStore adapter creates ES5 props for your model instead of "knockout" properties. I guessing that these will be easier for slickgrid to bind to.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! But I've a question, changing the adapter has some side effect in my existing knockout views?         doesn't this change work for IE 8 according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367365/how-does-breezejs-track-property-changes?

Comment: The Breeze 'backingStore' adapter will only work with ES5 capable browsers, which means IE9 and above.  The knockout adapter works with older browsers via an ES5 shim. Breeze currently only supports a single model library adapter per application, and it's probably not a good idea anyway to have more than one.  Another possibility if you need to stick with ko but need to unwrap a ko'd entity, take a look at knockout's 'toJS' method.

Comment: Really thank you! Another beginner's question, using ko.toJS will break the breeze entities tracking? if so, that would break the magic between updating the data in the slickgrid and saving the changes to the entities with breeze. I come from the silverlight mvvm ria services world, there you loaded the data in the domaincontext showed it on a datagrid, changed the data and domaincontext.submit sent the modified entities to the server. Breeze knockout and slickgrid are closer technology that I found to this moment in the html javascript world

Comment: Personal bias here ..., but in the interests of simplicity I would go with  Angular via the backingStore adapter.  Your slickgrid should work just like you expect and angular's mvvm architecture should work fine for any other controls. But... I don't really know what restrictions you are operating under.

Comment: Hello @Jay, I follow your advice, I'm trying Breeze, Angular and SlickGrid with mvvm architecture, but seems that there're a problem, when I load and bind the data with $scope.$apply(), I got: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, in google that error, looks like angular tries to clone the data on the view, but it fails for breeze objects. This problem also happen with wijgrid [link](http://wijmo.com/topic/wijgrid-will-not-play-with-angular-and-breeze-together/). So, what do you think? Thank you

Comment: This is possibly due to circularity issues. A object with a property that refers to an object that has a reference back to the initial object.  This is a perfectly legitimate javascript construct but each binding library or grid has its own rules about how this should be handled.  See the angular and slickGrid docs about dealing with circular refs.

Comment: Again you were right! The problem was mine, a little bit problem with the binding. I think I'll write an article at the end of my test. Thank you

Comment: Any comments (or criticism) of Breeze in any public forum is appreciated :)